# Setting null value to integer

Tags: java, string

How can i set null  to integer variable initially instead of "0". I know already by default all int value is "0". I used `String.valueOf()` method etc. I dont want to print as "null". I want to print blank like " ". I get number format exception. Please give one solution for that.

Thanks in advance

Here is the code

```
public class IntegerDemo {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String id="";


        System.out.println(""+Integer.parseInt(id));

    }
}
```

Comment: if(Integer.parseInt(id)==0){  System.out.println(" ");}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sure you are over-complicating the problem, it is a real simple thing to do. Check the code below:

```
Integer i = null;
System.out.println(i == null ?"":i);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use  [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) wrapper class instead of primitive

```
Integer myInt= null;
```

For object references you can set null.But you cannot to `primitives`.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to stick with the `java.lang.Integer` class.

```
String id = ""
Integer test = null;

if (!"".equals(id))
{
   test = Integer.parseInt(id);
}
```

Comment: `parseInt` is the method.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an instance of `Integer` with its primary value as `null` is meaningless, but you can do this on declaration:

```
Integer id = null;
```

The reason you're getting `NumberFormatException` is laid out [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> An exception of type NumberFormatException is thrown if any of the following situations occurs:
>
> - **The first argument is null or is a string of length zero.**
> - The radix is either smaller than Character.MIN_RADIX or larger than Character.MAX_RADIX.
> - Any character of the string is not a digit of the specified radix, except that the first > character may be a minus sign '-' ('\u002D') or plus sign '+' ('\u002B') provided that the string is longer than length 1.
> - The value represented by the string is not a value of type int.

You can't call `Integer.parseInt("")` or `Integer.parseInt(null)`, with that limitation.

Answer (score 0):

If you parse `null` or `blank` as int it will throw `numberFormatException`. Check for that before parsing:

```
try{
   System.out.println(StringUtils.isNotBlank(id)?Integer.parseInt(id):"");
}
catch(NumberFormatException e){
   System.out.println("Not A Number");
}
```

Also be sure if string has not number by catching exception. `StringUtils.isNotBlank()` will check for both `null` as well as `blank`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parse, we can use `Integer.valueOf(null);`

Answer (score -1):

```
Integer int = null;
```

ints are primitives, they have default values different from null.

Comment: `int` is a reserved keyword; this isn't valid Java syntax.  Besides, the OP isn't referring to primitives.

Comment: Yes, I'm wrong with variable name, but obviously I was not referring to primitives as well.

Answer (score -1):

The simple boxed Integer `Integer i = null;` has already been supplied. Here is an alternative:

```
class NullableInt {
    private int value;
    private boolean isNull;
    public NullableInt() { isNull = true; }
    public NullableInt(int value) { 
      this.value = value; 
      isNull = false;
    }
    public NullableInt(String intRep) {
      try { value = Integer.parseInt(intRep);
      } catch (NumberFormatException) {
         isNull = true;
      }
    }
    boolean isNull() { return isNull; }
    void setNull(boolean toNull) { isNull = toNull; }
    void setValue(int value) { this.value = value; }
    int getValue() { return value; }
    @Override 
    public String toString() { return isNull ? "" : value; }
}

NullableInt integer1 = new NullableInt(56);
NullableInt integer2 = new NullableInt();

System.out.pritnln(integer1); // >> "56"
System.out.println(integer2); // >> ""

// and finally, to address the actual question:
String id = "";
System.out.println(new NullableInt(id)); // >> ""
```